# videojs - Property "text" exists but compiler says it does not. (activeCues[0].text)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, video.js

I'm trying to access the text property, activeCues[0].text. I get a Typescript error saying "Property 'text' does not exist on type 'TextTrackCue'. But I can see that the property does exist in the Variables pane in Visual Studio Code. I can also print out the value of the text property in the Debug Console with "console.log". Please see the attached screen shots.

I am using video.js v7.15.4 (almost latest) and @types/video.js v7.3.27 (the latest). I also tried used video.js v.7.16.0 (the latest).

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit - I found out how to get the compile to ignore the error. Before the statement accessing the text property, I can put:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post code as text instead of image.

Comment: There is no `text` property shown in the document of [TextTrackCue](https://docs.videojs.com/texttrackcuelist#~TextTrackCue)

Comment: You may cast `activeCue` to `any`, or to the exact type derived from `TextTrackCue` which contains `text` property if you know.

Comment: @Ricky Mo - The images were not for the purpose of posting code. They were only to show the intellisense error and the property value displayed by VsCode.

Comment: Since it's not a documented property (even though it's there) is probably why I'm getting the error.